# ArrayList Iterator ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

My iterating while loop here is throwing a ConcurrentModificationException, it's listing line 7 (userPrograms it=(userPrograms)itr.next();) as the problem but I can't understand why. As far as I can tell this error is only thown when I m concurrently making modifications to the array list, but by the use of the if statements I am not making continuous and concurrent modifications, and to me it does not compute as to why line 7 would even be the reason for this error.

```
if (userList.size() == 0) {
        userPrograms p1 = new userPrograms(subsuserID, subsProgram, 0);
        userList.add(p1);
    } else {
        Iterator itr=userList.iterator();  
        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            userPrograms it=(userPrograms)itr.next();  
            if ((it.userID == subsuserID) && (it.program == subsProgram)) {
                it.program += 1;
            } else {
                userPrograms p1 = new userPrograms(subsuserID, subsProgram, 0);
                userList.add(p1);
            }
        }  
    }
    return userList;
}
```

The objective of this piece of code in specific the while loop is to iterate the arraylist and if the if statement is fulfilled preform actions on objects. Else it should add a new array object with the three values subsuserID, subsProgram and 0.

Thank you.

Comment: You're adding to the list whilst iterating it. You can't do that.

Comment: If you want to add to a list while iterating over it, use an index and a loop instead (e.g. while (i < list.size())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not making continuous and concurrent modifications

`ConcurrentModificationException` may be thrown during concurrent accesses by distinct threads but not only.

The [`ConcurrentModificationException` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) states :

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

And also (emphasis is mine):

> **Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread**. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception.**

You are in the last one case as you modify the List object during the iteration here :

```
userList.add(p1);
```

As alternative use a `while` statement with an `int` that maintains the current index of the iteration.
You could so add the element in the list :

This would give something like :

```
int i = 0;
int originalSize = userList.size(); // to prevent from iterating on elements 
                                    // added during the loop
while(i < originalSize){  
    userPrograms it= userList.get(i);  
    if ((it.userID == subsuserID) && (it.program == subsProgram)) {
        it.program += 1;
    } else {
        userPrograms p1 = new userPrograms(subsuserID, subsProgram, 0);
        userList.add(p1);
    }
    i++;
}
```